# Git checkout only giving me pointer files on some machines

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-lfs

I have some Jenkins pipeline jobs that run on multiple windows machines.  The machines have, as far as I can tell, identical configurations.  But on some of the machines, the checkout of git repositories leaves me with the git-lfs pointer files instead of the binary files that they point to.

If I then call `git lfs pull`, it will resolve the binary files.  But I'm trying to figure out why it isn't resolving them on checkout.

I have confirmed that on two machines, one in which it's working correctly and one where it's not, have identical versions of git (2.21.0) and git-lfs (2.7.2).

What might be causing git-lfs to not resolve the binary files on checkout?

Answer (score 1):

In order for Git LFS to check out files automatically, you need to have the filter options set up properly. You can run `git lfs env`, which should print three `git config` commands at the bottom. When properly configured, they should look something like this:

```
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f
```

If the value is empty or it looks wrong for your system, you should configure it appropriately, or use `git lfs install --skip-repo` to install it on a per-user basis (or use one of the other options to that command to install it elsewhere).

Note that if you're not sure where it's set on the systems where it works, you can check by using `git config -l --show-origin`, and then copy the configuration to an identical place on the other system.